# $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'lang', value); dosn't work

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, fullcalendar

I'm trying to change the language of a fullcalendar dynamically depending of the language selected in my interface. the dropdown which change the language is associated to a factory and to get the changed value I use a watch:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
        return langFctr.selectedLang;
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (oldValue != newValue) {
            $scope.selectedLang = newValue;
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'lang', $scope.selectedLang);
        }
    }
);
```

but the language didn't change in the fullcalendar this is my [code](http://pastebin.com/md8TiA4d)

Answer (score 2):

To use other languages of the FullCalendar,you must first include the language's js.These files are included in the lang/ directory.Now the files that you have included must be loaded via script.

For example,to include the es script use :-

```
    <script src='fullcalendar/lang/es.js'></script>
```

Now use the following snippet all inside a script tag :-

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#calendar').fullcalendar({
                        lang:'es'
                          });
                        });
```

Comment: always the same problem and also I want to change the language depending the dropdown